# How to Trigger an event on button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, triggers

[image]i have an appointments plugin with an option to select particular days in a checkbox manner. I have added a custom validation for the field. Everything works fine. when we click next and reaches next step there is a back button. When we click on the back button it takes to the form without refreshing the data so MY CUSTOM VALIDATION on days is not working.

Here is my code,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery(".ladda-button").attr('onclick','oniter()');
  },1750); 
 });

function oniter(){
  if (jQuery(".valid").find(".active").length>=1) {
    alert(123);
  } else {
    jQuery('.removeval').remove();
    jQuery(".validation_text").append("<font class='removeval'>Please Select a Day</font>");
  }
  jQuery(".valid").on ('change',function(){
    jQuery(".validation_text").remove();
  });       
}
```

This is how my validation works. I want to trigger the entire process when the back button is clicked to ensure the validation occurs . How to do this any idea?

Comment: It would be great to actually have some markup so we can see what it looks like. I can't imagine what "in a checkbox manner", the buttons and the form look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(document).on('click','.ladda-button',function(){
    oniter();
  });
});

function oniter(){
  if (jQuery(".valid").find(".active").length>=1) {
    alert(123);
  } else {
    jQuery('.removeval').remove();
    jQuery(".validation_text").append("<font class='removeval'>Please Select a Day</font>");
  }
  jQuery(".valid").on ('change',function(){
    jQuery(".validation_text").remove();
  });
}
```

Comment: i am facing an issue now. it works with normal functionality flow. but when we check and uncheck the day and click the next button , the validation is not happening. ... Why is tht ?

Answer (score 0):

Your form's back button should have some class or ID, right?
So just trigger same setTimeout when back button is clicked.
f.e.

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.back-button',function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    jQuery(".ladda-button").attr('onclick','oniter()');
  },1750);
});
```

Comment: i tried this but nthng seems to work. i tried it both in code and console

Comment: without seeing all scene it is impossoble to say more